# How to access file in s3n when running a customized jar in Amazon Elastic MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am running the below step in my cluster in EMR:

./elastic-mapreduce -j CLUSTERID  -jar s3n://mybucket/somejar

```
                --main-class  SomeClass 
                --arg -conf --arg 's3n://mybucket/configuration.xml'
```

The SomeClass is Hadoop job and implements Runnable interface. It reads configuration.xml for parameters, but in the above command the SomeClass can not access "s3n://mybucket/configuration.xml" (no error reported). I tried "s3://mybucket/configuration.xml" and it does not work either. I am sure the file existed, since I can see it with "hadoop fs -ls s3n://mybucket/configuration.xml". Any suggestion for the problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here are the options to try

1. Use s3 instead of s3n.
2. Check the access permission for s3 bucket.
3. You can specify the log location and can check the log after job
   fails.You can create job like below

   elastic-mapreduce --create --name "j_flow_name"  --log-uri "s3://your_s3_bucket"

It gives you the more debug information.

3.

```
./elastic-mapreduce -j JobFlowId -jar s3://your_bucket --arg "s3://your_conf_file_bucket_name" --arg "second parameter"
```

For more detailed information [EMR CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-launch-custom-jar-cli.html)